# WPF treeview get object of parent node

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a treeview with the following structure:

```
Attribute1
  --Value11
  --Value12
Attribute2
  --Value21
  --...
...
```

The treeview is populated with an `HierarchicalDataTemplate` of custom classes `Attribute` and `Value`.

**Now I need to get the parent (attribute) of the currently selected item (value).**

What I tried:

```
DependencyObject obj = treeViewAttributes.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(treeViewAttributes.Items.CurrentItem);
DependencyObject parentNode = ((TreeViewItem)obj).Parent;
Attribute parentAttribute = treeViewAttributes.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(obj) as AttributeType;
```

However the first line doesn't retrieve the selected object, but the root node. And `ContainerFromItem(treeViewAttributes.SelectedItem)` returns `null`.

Comment: Could you add a reference of the parent object (Attribute) to the child class (Value)?

Comment: Unfortunately only the parent has a reference to its children and the classes shouldn't be altered unless there is any other possible solution.

Comment: [This link will help you with a little modification.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806259/wpf-treeview-get-parent-node/47232504#47232504)

Answer (score 1):

WPF has a reason not to easily return a parent of a tree node. It basically forces you to think of a TreeView in terms of logical vs visual representation. Every node in a tree logically contains an object which on its own level is always created prior to its child, so the best approach to take when you know that you will need access to a parent node is to have a reference to a parent within a child when the child is being created since the parent already always exists.
This approach is way more efficient than walking the visual tree in search of a parent

Comment: Although this is true, it is possible to bind multiple nodes to the same instance. The advantage to this is that they are visually linked in the tree.  There is no way to get the parent without walking the visual tree because the underlying instance has no way to track which parent is the visual parent of the TreeViewItem that is bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
private void yourTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (sender is TreeView && ((TreeViewItem)((TreeView)sender).SelectedItem).Parent != null)
    {
        TreeViewItem parent = (TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)((TreeView)sender).SelectedItem).Parent;  // This will give you the parent             
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws an exception:
`Unable to cast object of type 'Value' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.`

Answer (score 0):

I tried running through treeView and use GetHashCode for finding parent treeViewItem and it worked well for me. I don't know how the performance is, but I think that should not be a problem:

```
private TreeViewItem GetParent(TreeViewItem root, TreeViewItem child)
    {
        //Step 1: Search at current level
        foreach (TreeViewItem item in root.Items)
        {
            if (item.GetHashCode() == child.GetHashCode())
            {
                return root;
            }
        }

        //Step 2: Still not found, so step deeper
        TreeViewItem buffer;
        foreach (TreeViewItem item in root.Items)
        {
            buffer = GetParent(item, child);
            if (buffer != null)
            {
                return buffer;
            }
        }

        //Not found anything
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the helper class in this blog

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the first ancester of specified type
    /// </summary>
    public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current)
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current is T)
            {
                return (T)current;
            }
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        };
        return null;
    }
```

Then you can get the parent with this call

```
var parent = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<Attribute>(Value);
```