# WPF: TreeView get parent node

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Problem explained short:

```
 Node 1
     Child x
     Child Y
 Node 2
     Child z
```

When dealing with `TreeView` type, when selecting a parent node, the `SelectedItem` property returns an object of type `TreeViewItem` and the following works properly

```
 TreeViewItem parentNode = (TreeViewItem) treeView.SelectedItem;
```

This while, this property return a `String` when a value of a node is selected which means in that case the following will be true:

```
 Boolean valueType = treeView.SelectedItem is String; --> True
```

Accordingly, we cannot cast the object to the `TreeViewItem` anymore.

Assuming you got the following

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Childs>> treeModel;
```

And you want to know to which node the child belongs, how would you obtain the parent node element from the `TreeView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately all post in SO point out to the wrong solution, or a solution which may no longer work due to the reason I explained. (The same applies to all Microsoft documentation, maybe outdated)

There seems to be no `**Built-In**` feature to this, so decided to design my own solution. This problem can be solved, by creating a customized `TreeViewItem` class and adding a `ParentNodeValue` property.

```
public class AdvancedTreeViewItem<T>: TreeViewItem{
    public T ParentNodeValue {get; set;}
    public T RootParentNodeValue {get; set;}
}
```

And we can do the following to get the node value:

```
var selectedValue = (AdvancedTreeViewItem<String>)treeView.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(selectedValue.RootParentNodeValue);
```

In this approach, there is no way the `SelectedItem` property would return a `String`

Answer (score 0):

### Original Answer

> TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem should do the trick: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem(v=vs.110).aspx

### New Answer

First of all, it's weird you have a tree model of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Childs[]>>`:

- Shouldn't it be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Childs>>`? Otherwise you will have a `Childs` array as the model of a node, rather than a single `Childs`.
- How do you assign the model with the tree? If you are binding them, you will never get a parent node with a `String` model, because it should be of type `IGrouping<String, Childs[]>` (or `IGrouping<String, Childs>` if the last point is accepted). Then your problem became finding the corresponding `TreeViewItem` of that `IGrouping` thing, which could be done with `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`. You can't make such a hierarchy manually, neither, because if you add a `String` item into a `TreeView`, how could you add Children for it?

And if we ignore these quirks, just assume you have such a model hierarchy in your `TreeView`:

```
 string Node1
     Childs ChildX
     Childs ChildY
 string Node2
     Childs ChildZ
```

Now you want to get the corresponded `TreeViewItem` of a child, say ChildY. Your problem here is, **you cannot get it from `TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator`, because it is not there**, not as you assumed, you can't get it if its model is a string. You can only find that `TreeViewItem` in its parent `TreeViewItem`'s `ItemContainerGenerator`.

In this case, you have to traverse down the tree recursively, find the container of the child in every `TreeViewItem`'s `ItemContainerGenerator`.

Comment: There is no possible that would work as I said "the value type is String".

Comment: Okay, please check my revised answer.

Comment: @"IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Childs[]>>": yeah you are right, that was a typo, it is a solid object not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about casting the object to the TreeViewItem. It returns null every-time. I had a very similar problem to you and here is the solution that I found.

```
Node GetSelectedParentNode(){
object selectedItem = treeView.SelectedItem;
if(selectedItem == null)
    return null;   // No item is selected in treeview
else if(selectedItem is Node)
    return selectedItem;      // You already have a parent node selected
else if(selectedItem is Child)
    return FindParentNode(selectedItem as Child);   // Your main task
else
    return null;  // Exception case...
}
```

here is main function to search parent of a child node.

```
Node FindParentNode(Child child){
    // assume you have some list of Node binding to treeview
    foreach(Node node in NodesList)
         if(node.childs.Contains(child)
             return node;      // here is your target parent node
    return null;   // Exception case..
}
```

Now you can use this code as

```
Node parentNode = GetSelectedParentNode();
// Do your stuff here..
```

I hope it will help a lot of people suffering from same problem. Although solution is very simple but I posted this because I also have wasted my too much time searching for solution.